# I was rinsing my mouth and I swallowed without intention or wanting to swallowed

Tags: ramadan, doubts

I was rinsing my mouth and I swallowed without intention or wanting to swallowed, I wanted to spit it out now I’m scared that I did this on purpose is my fast still valid?

Comment: Are you hundred percent sure you wanted to swallow?

Comment: No I did not I wanted to spit it out I had no intention to swallow it

Comment: Ok your fast is still valid, I have utube channel so if you like please subscribe- https://youtube.com/channel/UCzCxGaMEv3U2WlmqoCjH-8w

Answer (score 0):

A fast does not break if it through forgetfulness i.e. you drink water not remembering you were fasting but it can break accidentally, the latter is your case.